# Access k8s Load Balancer running inside ec2 from outside

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-ec2

I am running a simple web application inside pods and have mapped them with load balaner. I was able to `curl` it from the ec2 machine but couldn't access it from outside. Am I missing something in configuration?. Here is my deployment and service yml.

**Service**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: load-balancer-service
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  selector:
    tag: frontend
  ports:
  - name: port-lb-k8s
    protocol: TCP
    port: 8080
    targetPort: 80
```

**Deployment**

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: frontend-deployment
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      tag: frontend
  replicas: 3 # tells deployment to run 2 pods matching the template
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        tag: frontend
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: frontend-container
        image: coitlearning/coit-frontend
```

**Ec2 Machine**

[image]

Comment: How you perform the curl? Using load balancr endpoints?

Comment: Yes, and it is working fine. I have attached a screenshot

Comment: Load balancer configuration is already there in question

Comment: the IP attached to the load balancer is private `172.x.x.x` it should not be reachable from out side

Comment: I can access ec2 public IP. How can I forward traffic to load balancer Private IP

Comment: better to create public load balancer and whitelist the traffic that you need. forwarding through ec2 does not seems reliable solutions

Comment: https://pastebin.com/kRQiPKFb try this and see if you can get public lb through nlb, which version of eks?

Answer (score 1):

In-order to create a service with an internet-facing Network Load Balancer that load balances to IP targets, you can use the following

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nlb-load-balancer-service
  namespace: default
  annotations:
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-type: external
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-nlb-target-type: ip
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-scheme: internet-facing
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 8080
      targetPort: 80
      protocol: TCP
  type: LoadBalancer
  selector:
    tag: frontend
```

You can get more details in [official-docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/network-load-balancing.html)